# Is Stack Overflow limited to "business" questions?

Tags: discussion, migration

Over on Stack Exchange site *[Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com)* we're noticing a few questions getting migrated from Stack Overflow. Most of them don't belong on *Programming Puzzles & Code Golf*, but that's not the point. The question I have is why they're being migrated at all.

My analysis of the commonality between exhibits [A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3019/getting-an-answer-from-a-string-of-digits), [B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3047/help-with-an-ioi-problem), [C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3075/help-at-an-ioi-problem) is that they're about "leisure" programming rather than business. But if I'm right that that's the reason that people are flagging them for migration, I don't see why they don't belong here. The FAQ says that Stack Overflow is for

> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm...
>
> ... practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Are people interpreting that to mean that only problems encountered in the day job are valid? And if so, should they be?

Comment: Each of those should have been closed as 'not a real question' - I'm sure I seen somewhere recently: _'Don't migrate crap.'_

Comment: Define "leisure programming". If you mean, "writing code with no practical purpose for competitions", I actually thought that was kinda what CodeGolf was all about...

Comment: @Shog: As things stand CodeGolf.SE is for posting challenging tasks for which there is an *objective criterion* for selecting a winner among the entries. Under those conditions random *"I don't know how to solve this."* questions are rarely on topic. I have been poking around the edges of what changes the denizens might accept to our current format; time will tell.

Comment: The source for "Don't migrate crap!" is -- as far as I know -- [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149432/mark-trapp). @Mr.Disappointment

Answer (score 12):

They don't belong on SO, but it's not because they're not business related. I can see why people would have thought they belonged on codegolf if they hadn't read the faq over there. Having looked at the faq now, I agree they don't quite fit on codegolf.

My inclination would have been to close all three of them as "Not a real question". The first one is phrased as a challenge rather than a question, and they all feel very "give me teh codez" with a helping of "go read this long involved problem statement I can't be bothered to summarize".

If the questions had taken a specific part of the problem, shown what they had tried, and asked with help fixing some specific problem they're having with it then they'd be just fine.

Comment: +1 `give me teh codez`.  On a second consideration, I concur.

Answer (score 0):

Not having seen those questions, I would've suggested migrating them simply for the references (in two questions) to [IOI](http://www.ioi2011.or.th/).  As for the first question, it sounds like a 'Programming Puzzle', but I agree, it probably shouldn't have been migrated.  Just my $0.02.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your first sentence? Why does a question which mentions the IOI not belong here?

Comment: As a programming competition, I would've categorized these questions as a better fit to [codegolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) instead of questions for the more general audience of [so].  I believe that there are often nuances to answering questions at a competition which go beyond simply submitting a functional program.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get paid to face an 'actual problem.' You could be doing volunteer programming for a nonprofit, or sharpening your incisors chewing on an open source project. The distinction at hand is that hypothetical questions, as in puzzles, interview questions, and general slag, are not encouraged.

Comment: I disagree. You can post questions related to puzzles, interview questions and whatnot, the distinction is formulating the question appropriately to convey exactly which part you're having trouble with - the playing field, so to speak, is irrelevant.

Comment: IOW, "dance for my amusement" questions.

Comment: @shog iow? What's that?

Comment: @Mr in theory, sure. Ever seen one like that, as opposed to all those verbatim dumps of interview questions or puzzles scraped from web sites.

Comment: @Ros: In Other Words